# using jquery how can i assign the output of sum of two numbers to interval:

Tags: jquery

I tried to assign to the value of `i` to the interval:` element, I tried with the following code, but it is not working, please help me to solve this

```
var speed = 1000;
var delay = 1000;
var i = speed + dealy
$('#carousel-example-actions').carousel({
interval: i
});
```

Comment: Could it be the typo in your code? You have defined `delay` but referred to it as `dealy`. Also, don't forget a semi-colon at the end of that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This use parseInt

```
var speed = 1000;
var delay = 1000;
var i = speed + dealy;
$('#carousel-example-actions').carousel({
interval: parseInt(i)
});
```

Comment: thanks it works for me perfectly, if you don't mine please explain how the parseint works?

Comment: interval accepts number. but you were passing "i" directly and it was taking as a string. parseInt() converts string number or double value into integer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now i understand clearly on parseInt()